# How to block incoming and allow outgoing mails for a no-reply user on Sendmail?

Tags: email, sendmail

I am trying to block inbound emails for no-reply user and allow it to send emails at the same time. I tried editing the configuration in `/etc/mail/virtusertable` with:

```
no-reply@example.com     error:5.7.0:550 Invalid Address
```

But when I tried sending a test email with `root`, the email got bounced back to my postmaster with the "Invalid Address" error. So, I guess the setting affects both sending and receiving of mails.

As I need to receive emails for some other users, is there anyway I can block incoming mails and yet allow outgoing ones without closing inbound port 25 on my firewall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add an entry to your `/etc/aliases` file like so:

```
no-reply: /dev/null
```

Be sure to rebuild the aliases database with the `newaliases` command afterwards.

#### References

- [How can I point an email alias at /dev/null?](http://help.hardhathosting.com/question.php/220)

Answer (score 1):

> As I need to receive emails for some other users, is there anyway I
>   can block incoming mails and yet allow outgoing ones without closing
>   inbound port 25 on my firewall?

If you are running a server, you must be aware that there are always attacks, so the entry in `virtusertable` may not be enough.

To block `no-reply` emails and block a lot of other UCE(unsolicited commercial email)
you can use [spamassassin](http://spamassassin.apache.org/) as server (spamd) in connection with `spamass-milter`.

The `milter` approach is very nice, since you can parse emails and reject while they are being received.

Blocking users are done by:

```
# /etc/spamassassin/local.cf

blacklist_from no-reply@*
blacklist_from direkt-invest@*
blacklist_from *@*direkt-invest*

whitelist_from firend@example.com
```

There a lot of other rules you can do with `local rules`

To block emails with specific content use

```
body  LOCAL_UCE1_RULE /Viagra/
score LOCAL_UCE1_RULE 1000.0
```

You can block most of UCE by using [DNS Blocklists](https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/DnsBlocklists).

You need also often fine tune your rules and run `sa-update` the SpamAssassin rule updates.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure there is no `no-reply` OS account
2. Remove "custom error" entry i virtusertable